# How can I make attemp_login() function in php with mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

**WHAT I HAVE:** 
I have this function called `get_name()` that returns the name of the user from database if excisting username and passwords are provided in the parametres of it and it works perfectly. CODE:

```
function get_name($theusername, $thepassword){
    $host = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $database = 'website';
    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);

    $theusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $theusername);
    $thepassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $thepassword);
    $thepassword = md5($thepassword);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '{$theusername}' AND password = '{$thepassword}'";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    return $row['name'];

    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

**WHAT I WANT:** 
I want to make a function called `attempt_login()` that should return `true` if the username AND password is correct else it should return `false`.
[DATABASE SCREENSHOT](http://rabwahnetwork.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/image1.png)
CAN ANYONE DO THIS FOR ME?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the difference between your `get_name()` and `attempt_login()` use cases?  I don't understand what `attempt_login()` would do that is different from this function.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the $row['name'] is set.

Instead of `return $row['name']`, use `return isset($row['name'])`.

The `isset` function returns a `boolean`.

`PHP` documentation for `isset()`
http://php.net/isset